# Goodness of fit for generalized linear model

Tags: generalized-linear-model, repeated-measures, goodness-of-fit

How to measure the "goodness of fit" in generalized linear models for repeated measures. To make clear: I'm searching for something which is based on the (deviance) residuals, something like an adj. R^2 for linear models. Something that could make me state about the efficacy of the model? Any thought would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Nakagawa and Schielzeth have some comments on R2 in GLMMs, which is more accurately what "GLMs for repeated measures" are - this might help clear up some confusion when you're looking for answers. Whether you're a biologist or not, I find Nakagawa generally produces very interpretable papers for people that are not professional statisticians.
http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.2041-210x.2012.00261.x/full